# result from mysql_fetch_array without row 0

Tags: mysql, arrays, fetch

i've got this here

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
 echo  "<li><a href='".$root_dir
        .strtoupper(utf8_encode($row['country']))
        ."/ci"
        .utf8_encode($row['id'])
        ."/"
        .cleanURLString(strtolower(utf8_encode($row['name'])))
        .".html'>".utf8_encode($row['name'])
        ."</a> ("
        .utf8_encode(round($row['distance'],2)  )
        ." km)</li>";
        }
```

How can I filter this result so I got only the rows 1 until XX ... without row 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Just call mysql_fetch_array(...) once before the while loop.  Or use OFFSET in your SQL query...

Comment: Thanks for your comments...  I couldn't think straight... was a long night ;)

I have just limited the query... LIMIT 0 , XX => LIMIT 1 , XX

Answer (score 0):

Fetch one row before starting the `while` loop.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 echo  "<li><a href='".$root_dir
```